# "Read-only file system" under centos CD rescue mode

Tags: centos, rescue

I broke centos6.6 by changing libc, now I'm trying revert libc under CD rescue mode, failed as "read-only file system"
Am I on the right way or how should fix my system? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DISK1:=the harddisk with the libc-broken-CentOS-filesystem

I still can only read-access DISK1 under CD rescue mode, but after I **mounted DISK1 to another CentOS machine**, I could write-access DISK1, then **changed libc.so.6 to the old version**(2.12), CentOS on DISK1 can boot successfully now.